# Angular - Ionic 2 - Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to implement offline mode and I have done something like this.

In my `Page.ts` File

```
getnews() {

        this._newsservice.GetNews(this.NewsFilterOptions).subscribe(res => {
            this.newsArray = res;
            this.loadingnews = false;
        },
            err => {
                this.loadingnews = false;
            },
            () => {

            });
    }
```

In My `Service` File

```
GetNews(FilterOptions: any) {
        return this.utilitiesService.Get("news" + this.QueryBuilder(FilterOptions));
    }
```

MY `Utilities` File

```
public Get(endUrl: string) :Observable<any> { 

        if (this._AppConfig.IsOnline) { // If Online Get From Server
            ...
            return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + endUrl, options)
                .map(response => {
                    //SAVE HTTP RESPONSE TO DICTIONARY
                    this._OfflineService.Set(this.baseUrl + endUrl, response);
                    return response.json()
                });
        }
        else {

            this._OfflineService.Get(this.baseUrl + endUrl).then(val => {
                return Observable.of(val).map(o => o.json());
            }).catch((err) => {
                return Observable.throw("ERROR");
            });


            // FETCH HTTP RESPONSE FROM DICTIONARY
            //return Observable.of(Data).map(o => o);

        }


    }
```

Offline `Service`: I am using Ionic `LocalStorage`.

```
 Get(endUrl: string) {

    // Or to get a key/value pair
    return this.storage.get(endUrl);

}


 Set(endUrl: string , data: any) {

    // Or to get a key/value pair
    this.storage.set(endUrl,data).then((val) => {

    });
    }
```

Now Online Mode is Working Fine, However when the app goes offline, I am getting 
Cannot read property `subscribe` of undefined although I am returning observable.

Comment: You are trying to return an Observable from `Promise.then` which indeed will return undefined for `Promise` is **asynchronous**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Observable.fromPromise`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/frompromise.md).

In your `Get()` function , else section:

```
return Observable.fromPromise(this._OfflineService.Get(this.baseUrl + endUrl))
     .map(val => val.json())
     .catch((err) => {
                return Observable.throw("ERROR");
            });
```

This will convert the promise to an observable and you can use `map` to parse the json and subscribe in the end.

Comment: Getting Same Error.

Comment: @MissakBoyajian  you should return the observable. like `return Observable.fromPromise(...)`

Comment: one last question. the Val is returning set of properties like status - headers and some stuff. The data that I want is in the '_body' field. Why is ionic storage not returning only the data

Comment: If you want only that .. maybe store only json.. `this._OfflineService.Set(this.baseUrl + endUrl, response.json());`

Comment: Thanks all good. I am curios though on my initial code. Doesn't .then() make things synchronous. I am returning after I get the data?

Comment: anything you return from `then` will again be a promise.. It needs to be an `Observable` if you want to subscribe.. Another way to handle this is convert everything to promise and use `then` in the end